# Method not found in inherited generic type

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm playing with Typescript type system and generics, to see how far I could go. But it looks like it's failing on recognising inherited methods from generic types.

Consider this code (The full code in Typescript Playground: http://goo.gl/vGZj2z):

```
interface Functor<A> {
  flatMap <A,B> (f: (A) => B): Functor<B> // wrong?
}

interface Option<A> extends Functor<A> {
  getOrElse(orElse: A): A
}

class Some<A> implements Option<A> {
  private value: A
  constructor(a: A) {
    this.value = a;
  }
  flatMap <A,B> (f: (A) => B): Some<B> {
    return new Some(f(this.value))
  }
  getOrElse(orElse: A): A {
    return this.value
  }
}

var test: Option<Number> = new Some(9)
var bar: Option<String> = test.flatMap(numberToString)
```

I have this warning for the line `var bar`...:

```
Cannot convert 'Functor<String>' to 'Option<String>': Type 'Functor<String>' is missing property 'getOrElse' from type 'Option<String>'.
```

It's looking for `getOrElse` in `Functor<String>` and doesn't see it in `Option<String>`.

My guess is that the `Functor` definition is wrong, but I cannot see what should go in there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't ever shadow generic type parameters (like `A` in `Functor#flatMap`). It's very confusing.

The problem here is that TypeScript doesn't have a notion of saying that a function returns the same type as the calling object (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/285)). The definition of `Functor#flatMap` would ideally say that it returns the same `Functor`-subtype as the object it was called on, but this isn't supported in the type system today.

You can write this instead to work around the problem:

```
var bar = <Option<String>>x;
```

Comment: Thanks the tip for the shadowing, I'll try to change my habits! As for the issue itself, it's not a blocker but sounds strange. I'll keep an eye on next releases. Thanks again !